# Plugin to convert latex to image

Tags: scripts, latex

Is there any plugin which can be installed on server or just kept on server to convert latex equations to images?

[image: sceenshot]

I want to give input like

```
A_{m,n}=\begin{pmatrix}a_{1,1}&a_{1,2}&\cdots&a_{1,n}\\a_{2,1}&a_{2,2}&\cdots&a_{2,n}\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\a_{m,1}&a_{m,2}&\cdots&a_{m,n}\end{pmatrix}
```

and get the output as an image

I have gone through a [GitHub solution](https://github.com/redsymbol/l2p) and figured out [this bash script](https://github.com/bennokr/latex-equation-from-image/tree/master/tex2im-1.8), but it does not support for some Latex equations like

```
A_{m,n}=\begin{pmatrix}a_{1,1}&a_{1,2}&\cdots&a_{1,n}\\a_{2,1}&a_{2,2}&\cdots&a_{2,n}\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\a_{m,1}&a_{m,2}&\cdots&a_{m,n}\end{pmatrix}
```

and

```
M=\begin{bmatrix}\frac56&\frac16&0\\[0.3em]\frac56&0&\frac16\\[0.3em]0&\frac56&\frac16\end{bmatrix}
```

[image: see the screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Let say your latex file is `myfile.tex`,
then you can do:
`latex myfile.tex` to produce a dvi file. (i.e myfile.dvi)
To convert the dvi file to image,
run:
`dvipng myfile.dvi`
or:
`dvigif myfile.dvi`

This process can easily be of course be automated with a shell script or setting an alias.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/) to do that. It has a lot of features to do what you want with latex equations as far as i know.

The [Imagemagick tag on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imagemagick) has posts related to your question.

This is a plugin for ImageMagick: [github LatexEquationPreview](https://github.com/divinites/LatexEquationPreview)

Comment: Could you provide an example of a conversion like that?

Comment: [reference creating special effects with mathematical expressions+images](https://imagemagick.org/script/fx.php) i guess you can do the same with equations